# How to fix flexmojos: Type was not found - UncaughtErrorEvent (Flex 4.1)

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flexmojos

I'm using flexmojos 3.8 with flex compiler 4.1.0.16248

My Project compiles fine in Flash Builder, but with flexmojos / maven I get the following Error:

```
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: UncaughtErrorEvent
```

The Flex Code looks like this:

```
loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);
```

The Flex Compiler 4.1 should know the type UncaughtErrorEvent -  Why does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution:

[flexmojos mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/flex-mojos@googlegroups.com/msg08614.html)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
  <version>${flex.version}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
  <version>${flex.version}</version>
  <classifier>10.1</classifier>
  <type>swc</type>
</dependency>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <targetPlayer>10.1</targetPlayer>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to target flash player 10.1 instead of 10.0

Not sure how to do it in Maven, but that's likely your problem.